# How to take values from List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>

Tags: android

I want to take Latlong values stored in Hash map as key value pairs.

```
List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes
```

'routes' hold the values. I want to get those values

[image: structure]

Comment: routes.get(x).get(y).get(z)...

Comment: You can get a value with somethings like routes.get(0).get(0).get("yourKey") but can you be more precise about the structure of this combination of collections ?

Comment: [link] (https://postimg.org/image/qtngmsd9p/) @Y. Tarion kindly have a look at image for structure... Thank You

Comment: Oh ok, so if you do `routes.get(0).get(0)` you get a `HashMap<String,String>` that I'll call "latlong". `latlong.get("lat")` will return the latitude and `latlong.get("lng")` the longitude

Comment: Yeah thnx Tarion for solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you break it down into the parts so you understand it:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> route = routes.get(0);
HashMap<String, String> position = route.get(0);
String latitude = position.get("lat");
String longitude = position.get("lng");
```